# How I coul get a JSON like this?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to get a JSON with arrays, how I could do it?

```
//JSON I need to get

{"keywords":[{"keyword":"kw1", "tags":["sample"]},{"keyword":"kw2", "tags":["sample, sample2"]}]}

//For now, I got this

$keywords = array("kw1", "kw2");

$tags= array("sample", "sample2");

function Keywords($keywords, $tags){

$fields= array("keywords" => $keywords);

$jsondata = json_encode($fields);

print_r($jsondata );

}

//output

{"keywords":["kw1","kw2"]}
```

I expect the output like this:

```
{"keywords":[{"keyword":"kw1", "tags":["sample"]},{"keyword":"kw2", "tags":["sample, sample2"]}]}
```

Comment: And why for `kw1` is only one tag?

Comment: Because each kw can have one or more tags, still, I do not know how to assign tags for different kwS (if using different tag arrays or using the index). I think that I will assign the same tags for each kw.

Comment: _“Because each kw can have one or more tags“_ - then you need to _start_ with a data structure that reflects that. Right now, there is _no_ correlation between a specific keyword and any specific tags whatsoever, you only have two “independent” arrays. Your _input data_ is not suitable at this point to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `tags` in the first element of your example is supposed to be `["sample, sample2"]` as well (otherwise you would really have to explain by what logic you want to achieve at the result as shown) …

```
$keywords = array("kw1", "kw2");
$tags= array("sample", "sample2");

$result = new StdClass;
$result->keywords = [];

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
  $temp = new StdClass;
  $temp->keyword = $keyword;
  $temp->tags = [];
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $temp->tags[] = $tag;
  }
  $result->keywords[] = $temp;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Basically two nested loops over the keywords and the tags, and inside a new temporary object is created an then appended to the result array.

Comment: This would create `"tags":["sample","sample2"]`, but if you really want the tags as _one_ comma-separated string instead of an array, the inner foreach loop needs to be removed, and the line before that becomes `$temp->tags = implode(', ', $tags);` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Finally, I fixed it with an only loop:  foreach ($keywords as $kw) {
      $kw["keywords"][] = array("keyword" => $kw, "tags" => $tags);
    }